# Pairing android device with App on TV emulator

Tags: android, samsung-smart-tv

I'm trying to get messaging system work, on samsung emulator 3.5.1.

Got android app that properly discovers emulator. Troubles start when I try to connect:

```
String url='http://'+tvUrl+':8008'+'/ws/app/'+appId+'/connect';
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost();
request.addHeader('Accept-Language', 'en-us');
request.addHeader('sldeviceid', '12345');           
request.addHeader('vendorid', 'VenderMe');
request.addHeader('devicename', 'IE-Client');
request.addHeader('productid', 'SMARTDev');
request.addHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate');
request.addHeader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1;Trident/5.0)');
request.addHeader('Accept', '*/*');

request.setURI(new URI(url));

client.execute(request);
```

appId is hardcoded value read from emulator:

```
alert('App id: '+ curWidget.id);
```

As a result I'm getting error 404, while app is running on emulator.

What am I missing? What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The emulator version you are using is too old. You should use 4.0+ if you want to use AllShare functionality with SDK.

Comment: Thanks for answer, however I am unable to validate it, since we dropped this technology, so wont mark as accepted